# Use uPNP to configure port forwarding on my router to Ubuntu machine

Tags: internet, firewall

I just loaded up a older computer of mine to run a server for a game I'm working on, (it's a template server) and I need to forward ports 3200 and 3201, so that it can be accessed both on my local network and outside the network. Now, I believe I have the right settings done in my router, for I used to run RSPS (runescape private servers) a long time ago; but when ever I go to a website to check if the port it open (or try running the game on a different computer hooked up to the same network) it fails/says its still closed.

Now, I was just wondering if you guys could give me some help, on getting this machine to do and work the way I want it to. I have not done any port forwarding or anything in the actual OS, but that is mostly because I can't really find any tutorials/sites with much help on that.

P.S. The server is made in python and I have gotten that up and running so far.

Comment: This may be slightly outside the scope of Ubuntu, as port forwarding on a router is a separate issue from Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to forward any ports on the PC if you want to reach a server on the PC. By default there's no packet filter ("personal firewall") in Ubuntu, all ports are open.

Please double-check that you really forwarded the ports in the router, because that is where you need to forward the ports. Make sure that you forwarded the ports to the correct IP address / machine name.

You can run

```
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep 3200
```

to see if your server really is listening on port 3200 (change to 3201 to check for port 3201, of course).

Comment: FYI: `so that it can be accessed both on my local network and outside the network` that's what they want, they need it visible externally, so your answer does not qualify as a complete answer.  As well, port forwarding is at the router, so...